# Why are floating point operations much faster with a warmup phase?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, floating-point

I initially wanted to test something different with floating-point performance optimisation in Java, namely the performance difference between the division by `5.0f` and multiplication with `0.2f` (multiplication seems to be slower without warm-up but faster with by a factor of about 1.5 respectively).

After studying the results I noticed that I had forgotten to add a warm-up phase, as suggested so often when doing performance optimisations, so I added it. And, to my utter surprise, it turned out to be about 25 times faster in average over multiple test runs.

I tested it with the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    float[] test = new float[10000];
    float[] test_copy;

    //warmup
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        fillRandom(test);

        test_copy = test.clone();

        divideByTwo(test);
        multiplyWithOneHalf(test_copy);
    }

    long divisionTime = 0L;
    long multiplicationTime = 0L;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        fillRandom(test);

        test_copy = test.clone();

        divisionTime += divideByTwo(test);
        multiplicationTime += multiplyWithOneHalf(test_copy);
    }

    System.out.println("Divide by 5.0f: " + divisionTime);
    System.out.println("Multiply with 0.2f: " + multiplicationTime);
}

public static long divideByTwo(float[] data)
{
    long before = System.nanoTime();

    for (float f : data)
    {
        f /= 5.0f;
    }

    return System.nanoTime() - before;
}

public static long multiplyWithOneHalf(float[] data)
{
    long before = System.nanoTime();

    for (float f : data)
    {
        f *= 0.2f;
    }

    return System.nanoTime() - before;
}

public static void fillRandom(float[] data)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    for (float f : data)
    {
        f = random.nextInt() * random.nextFloat();
    }
}
```

**Results *without* warm-up phase:**

```
Divide by 5.0f: 382224
Multiply with 0.2f: 490765
```

**Results *with* warm-up phase:**

```
Divide by 5.0f: 22081
Multiply with 0.2f: 10885
```

Another interesting change that I cannot explain is the turn in what operation is faster (division vs. multiplication). As earlier mentioned, without the warm-up the division seems to be a tad faster, while with the warm-up it seems to be twice as slow.

I tried adding an initialization block setting the values to something random, but it didn't not effect the results and neither did adding multiple warm-up phases. The numbers on which the methods operate are the same, so that cannot be the reason.

What is the reason for this behaviour? What is this warm-up phase and how does it influence the performance, why are the operations so much faster with a warm-up phase and why is there a turn in which operation is faster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before the warm up Java will be running the byte codes via an interpreter, think how you would write a program that could execute java byte codes in java.  After warm up, hotspot will have generated native assembler for the cpu that you are running on; making use of that cpus feature set.  There is a significant performance difference between the two, the interpreter will run many many cpu instructions for a single byte code where as hotspot generates native assembler code just as gcc does when compiling C code.  That is the difference between the time to divide and to multiply will ultimately be down to the CPU that one is running on, and it will be just a single cpu instruction.

The second part to the puzzle is hotspot also records statistics that measure the runtime behaviour of your code, when it decides to optimise the code then it will use those statistics to perform optimisations that are not necessarily possible at compilation time.  For example it can reduce the cost of null checks, branch mispredictions and polymorphic method invocation.

In short, one must discard the results pre-warmup.

Brian Goetz wrote a very good article [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/) on this subject.

========

APPENDED: overview of what 'JVM Warm-up' means

JVM 'warm up' is a loose phrase, and is no longer strictly speaking a single phase or stage of the JVM.  People tend to use it to refer to the idea of where JVM performance stabilizes after compilation of the JVM byte codes to native byte codes.  In truth, when one starts to scratch under the surface and delves deeper into the JVM internals it is difficult not to be impressed by how much Hotspot is doing for us.  My goal here is just to give you a better feel for what Hotspot can do in the name of performance, for more details I recommend reading articles by Brian Goetz, Doug Lea, John Rose, Cliff Click and Gil Tene (amongst many others).

As already mentioned, the JVM starts by running Java through its interpreter.  While strictly speaking not 100% correct, one can think of an interpreter as a large switch statement and a loop that iterates over every JVM byte code (command).  Each case within the switch statement is a JVM byte code such as add two values together, invoke a method, invoke a constructor and so forth.  The overhead of the iteration, and jumping around the commands is very large.  Thus execution of a single command will typically use over 10x more assembly commands, which means > 10x slower as the hardware has to execute so many more commands and caches will get polluted by this interpreter code which ideally we would rather focused on our actual program.  Think back to the early days of Java when Java earned its reputation of being very slow; this is because it was originally a fully interpreted language only.

Later on JIT compilers were added to Java, these compilers would compile Java methods to native CPU instructions just before the methods were invoked.  This removed all of the overhead of the interpreter and allowed the execution of code to be performed in hardware.  While execution within hardware is much faster, this extra compilation created a stall on startup for Java.  And this was partly where the terminology of 'warm up phase' took hold.

The introduction of Hotspot to the JVM was a game changer.  Now the JVM would start up faster because it would start life running the Java programs with its interpreter and individual Java methods would be compiled in a background thread and swapped out on the fly during execution.  The generation of native code could also be done to differing levels of optimisation, sometimes using very aggressive optimisations that are strictly speaking incorrect and then de-optimising and re-optimising on the fly when necessary to ensure correct behaviour.  For example, class hierarchies imply a large cost to figuring out which method will be called as Hotspot has to search the hierarchy and locate the target method.  Hotspot can become very clever here, and if it notices that only one class has been loaded then it can assume that will always be the case and optimise and inline methods as such.  Should another class get loaded that now tells Hotspot that there is actually a decision between two methods to be made, then it will remove its previous assumptions and recompile on the fly.  The full list of optimisations that can be made under different circumstances is very impressive, and is constantly changing.  Hotspot's ability to record information and statistics about the environment that it is running in, and the work load that it is currently experiencing makes the optimisations that are performed very flexible and dynamic.  In fact it is very possible that over the life time of a single Java process, that the code for that program will be regenerated many times over as the nature of its work load changes.  Arguably giving Hotspot a large advantage over more traditional static compilation, and is largely why a lot of Java code can be considered to be just as fast as writing C code.  It also makes understanding microbenchmarks a lot harder; in fact it makes the JVM code itself much more difficult for the maintainers at Oracle to understand, work with and diagnose problems.  Take a minute to raise a pint to those guys, Hotspot and the JVM as a whole is a fantastic engineering triumph that rose to the fore at a time when people were saying that it could not be done.  It is worth remembering that, because after a decade or so it is quite a complex beast ;)

So given that context, in summary we refer to warming up a JVM in microbenchmarks as running the target code over 10k times and throwing the results away so as to give the JVM a chance to collect statistics and to optimise the 'hot regions' of the code.  10k is a magic number because the Server Hotspot implementation waits for that many method invocations or loop iterations before it starts to consider optimisations.  I would also advice on having method calls between the core test runs, as while hotspot can do 'on stack replacement' ([OSR](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2011-11-22-what-the-heck-is-osr-and-why-is-it-bad-or-good)), it is not common in real applications and it does not behave exactly the same as swapping out whole implementations of methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the part with how the warm-up phase influences it and how that works? I still don't fully understand it and there doesn't seem to be much explanation on it in other places.

Comment: @1337 that is not a quick question to answer, but I have added a section to the end of the question that gives more detail.  There is no single quick answer as 'warm-up' is actually a loose term used to cover many aspects of the JVM, but I will give it a go.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks very much. I will put an extra 50 reputation bounty for you for that, but I think I have to wait another day before I can put a bounty :)

Comment: Put the bounty on the question, I will not award it yet so that this answer (and the question) get a bit more attention :)

Answer (score 4):

You aren't measuring anything useful "without a warmup phase"; you're measuring the speed of interpreted code times how long it takes for the on-stack replacement to be generated.  Maybe divisions cause compilation to kick in earlier.

There are sets of guidelines and various packages for building microbenchmarks that don't suffer from these sorts of issues.  I would suggest that you read the guidelines and use the ready-made packages if you intend to continue doing this sort of thing.

Comment: While this does answer the first part of my question, it still doesn't answer the second part: Why the turn in which operation is faster?

Comment: It very much answers that part of your question.  The division code is probably getting compiled sooner than the multiplication code.

Comment: @1337 chris answers that since it's due to the hot spot jvm.