# Which performs better : for each or iterator in LinkedList?

Tags: java, collections, foreach, linked-list, iterator

I have been checking the performance of **for each** vs **Iterator** in traversing LinkedList through a program:

```
public class ListTraversePerformance {
    public static void main(String... args){
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
            list.add("Any String" + i);
        }
        Iterator i = list.iterator();
        String x;
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(String j: list){
             x = j;

        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(i.hasNext()){ 
            x= (String)i.next();

        }
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.print((t2-t1) + "  " + (t3-t2));
    }
}
```

The Ouput that i get is different every time i.e. sometimes the first loop run fast and sometimes second.

MY QUESTION:

I think the **for each** loop should run slow than the second **Iterator**. I think in `for each` loop the linked list should traverse from the beginning every time making its complexity `O(n^2)` as compared to `O(n)` complexity of `Iterator`. Am I Correct? and if yes then why are the results not as I expect...

Comment: LinkedList is always traversed from start node to end.

Comment: No, you are not correct. a foreach loop doesn't need to iterate from the beginning each time.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I have an idea of that,, my question is  why not the for each loop is running slow.

Comment: @sagar different execution will give u different execution time even for same piece of code depending on the current cpu status. In short there is no time complexity difference between two cases as linkedlist is always traversed from start to end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are pretty much equivalent, and they both are O(n) as each element is being iterated exactly once.  Neither repeats the iteration.

The for each loop uses an iterator under the hood.  It is syntactic sugar for iteration over objects that implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which in turn creates an Iterator.  And thus when I said that the two were pretty much equivalent, I meant that literally.

Micro benchmarking is very difficult to get right. The biggest gotcha is that we end up thinking that we are timing one thing, but in reality we are timing something else; and it takes a lot of digging to pick it all apart to understand what is really happening. Have a read of the answer to the following related post, it will explain why the times vary so much and a little about how you can work with that.   [Why are floating point operations much faster with a warmup phase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583297/why-are-floating-point-operations-much-faster-with-a-warmup-phase/25583375#25583375).  The SO of that question made pretty much the same observation as yourself about a benchmark, only using floating point operations rather than list iteration.

The quick summary is 1) the JVM starts off executing code via an interpreter, and optimises hot regions of code on the fly, 2) GC and other backgrounds processes can interfere, some may be in the JVM and others may be outside of the JVM.

Comment: @sagar that is explained in the answer to that question, I have given a very quick summary of that post in this question but I would like to avoid duplicating that post here.